# Install libfreenect on anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

How to install libfreenect package from github to anaconda (python 3.6) ?
who can guide me because i did a lot of research but nothing was useful .
Thanks.

Link of Libfreenect: https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pip` like:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect
```

Comment: i already tried that and i got this error :

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\RHIM\\Ap
pData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-fuc7pjfw\\setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\RHIM\App
Data\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-fuc7pjfw\